# 500 internal server on wordpress backend - .htaccess configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error

it's my first ever asked question so please go easy on me :D I was visiting this website really often but it's a first time I couldn't handle things by myself

Problem is that after uploading MySQL database, changing links by SQL command, and uploading all site files to root directory of domain I can't access backend of my site.

I think it's some kind of problem with addressing, because modifying .htaccess file allowed me to see backend, but without any CSS (plain text) and internal server errors while trying to log in, log out and entering different options. My .htaccess file looks now like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Error I get from Apache log files goes like:

```
[Tue Nov 08 21:07:39.997724 2016] [core:error] [pid 12144:tid 140252266088192] [client 89.72.3.118:57358] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://aplagema.pl/wp-admin/
```

Code for this .htaccess was copied from one of similar threads from here, and modified by couple of more lines from various threads. I do not know any keywords for writing .htaccess, I don't know in which language it's written so I'm going around blind. My experience of uploading sites consisted only of akeeba backup kickstart and this is my first time uploading site manually (this time akeeba didn't work)

Site we are talking about can be seen at [www.aplagema.pl](http://aplagema.pl)

EDIT: Had to take site down, because client was unhappy with how it looked, link refers now to his old site.

Comment: With access control wildcard in allowed origins `* ` you have introduced a big security problem to your wordpress site. Regarding your problem, I think the last 2 rules are the issue.